# Instagram Authentication issue

Tags: instagram

In my app i have 3 different ways to use Instagram Auth and need to redirect to 3 different places dependant on the action. because of this I have 3 different auth URL's

My registered redirect URL is http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/

Auth URL 1 is

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='
    + ig_id
    + '&response_type=code&redirect_uri='
    + encodeURI('http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/?l=r');
```

Auth URL 2 is

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='
    + ig_id
    +'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='
    + encodeURI('http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/?l=g');
```

Auth URL 3 is

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='
    + ig_id
    +'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='
    + encodeURI('http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/?l=l');
```

Now all of these URL's return me to the correct URL with the code appended to it ready to turn into an access token.

Without the parameters inside the EncodeURI this lets me access the data I need. If I keep the paramters I get the HTTP400 error below

```
[23-Aug-2014 10:26:40 Europe/Berlin] Array
(
    [code] => 400
    [error_type] => OAuthException
    [error_message] => Redirect URI doesn't match original redirect URI
)
```

If you look at this page on Instagrams documentation it says it allows you to use parameters http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: It's not the parameter, I think it's the `encodeURI()` fault http://jsfiddle.net/zzkw0o9u/ maybe you just need to encode the parameter value, not the full URI

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem getting the access token by PHP, I issue that using the same URL of redirect_uri, for example:

If the Auth URL using is `http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/?l=l` after login in Instagram sends you to redirect_uri `http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/?l=l&code=<CODE>`. So in this file on the CURL parameters to get information or access token from Instagram use the same URL `http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/?l=l` with the same GET vars.

I know this is a old Post but this may be can helpful to sometone like me that ends in this post searching an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation shows

Registered Redirect URI
http://yourcallback.com/callback

You have

> My registered redirect URL is http://nameoftheapp.com/folder/

Try removing the ending slash...?